# Each() выдает только последнее значение массива

Tags: jquery

Помогите разобраться, к каждому rect svg привязывается объект, в консоле массив как надо выдает, а вот хочу привязать к объектам, у всех появляется только последнее значение массива. По всякому крутил, не получается, надеюсь на ваш опыт, подскажите пожалуйста!!! Элементы самые обычные типа:

```
<div id="bd-1"><div>
<div id="bd-2"><div>
<div id="bd-3"><div>
<div id="bd-4"><div>
<div id="bd-5"><div>
```

Сам код:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="mob_plan" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"viewBox="0 0 1060 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1060 1000" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect id="build-1" x="379" y="57" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="build-2" x="313" y="122" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="build-3" x="246" y="184" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/> 
    <rect id="build-4" x="177" y="254" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="build-5" x="109" y="346" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="build-6" x="42" y="457" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="k-3" x="649" y="282.5" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="k-2" x="759" y="476" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
    <rect id="k-1" x="918" y="254" fill="none" width="83" height="57"/>
</svg>

$('[id*="build-"]').each(function(){
    if($(window).width()<=767){ 
        var left = Math.round($(this).offset().left);
        var top = Math.round($(this).offset().top);
        var elem = $('[id*="bd-"]');
        $(elem).css('top', top);
        $(elem).css('left', left);
    }
});
```

Comment: var elem = $('[id*="bd-"]') метод .eq() надо применить

Comment: точно, затупил, спасибо))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас выбираются все дивы в этой строке `var elem = $('[id*="bd-"]');`
Необходимо применить один из методов фильтрации выборки, например, `eq()` с индексом от текущего объекта `this`.